# In powershell how can a simulate the shift key being held down?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to run the following 2 lines of code to open an access database. The issue is this database has an auto loaded model form that blocks the rest of the powershell script from running till it's closed.

```
$ms_access = New-Object -ComObject "Access.Application"
$ms_access.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\db.accdb", $false)
```

I can avoid the dialog when opening the database if the shift key is pressed. I've tested this  and it works. Now I would like to not have to hold the shift key while running my powershell script so is there a way in powershell to simulate the shift key being pressed? Not just a SendKey, but press and hold for the duration of the `OpenCurrentDatabase`?

Something like?

```
$ms_access = New-Object -ComObject "Access.Application"
Set-Shift-Down
$ms_access.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\db.accdb", $false)
Set-Shift-Up
```

This is for Powershell-v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'ld use [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event):

```
Add-Type @"
using System;                                                                     
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Tricks {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]                                                            
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);}
"@   

[system.reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")

#left shift key pressed
[tricks]::keybd_event([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::LShiftKey, 0x45, 0, 0);
... do stuff here
#left shift key released
[tricks]::keybd_event([System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::LShiftKey, 0x45, 0x2, 0);
```

if you don't want load `windows.forms` assembly use `0xA0` as value for `LShiftKey`

I really don't know native powershell way, p/invoke should work but I can't test it like you want to use it.