# Opening an Access database with PowerShell, simulating the shift key, as a service

Tags: windows, powershell, service

So I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447407/in-powershell-how-can-a-simulate-the-shift-key-being-held-down) question and got an answer. So I have my script that works when I run it as a user...

```
Add-Type @"
using System;                                                                     
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Tricks {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]                                                            
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);}
"@   

cd "C:\db_location\"

$ms_access = New-Object -ComObject "Access.Application"
[tricks]::keybd_event(0xA0, 0x45, 0, 0);
$ms_access.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\db_location\db_app.accdb", $false)
[tricks]::keybd_event(0xA0, 0x45, 0x2, 0); 

$ms_access.Run("do_work")
$ms_access.Quit() | Out-Null
```

No when setup a service to run this PowerShell is fails. It never reaches the `$ms_access.Run("do_work")` bit so that means the open didn't finish. The only reason the open wouldn't finish is because the simulated shift key isn't working.

How can I get the `keybd_event` to work when this script is run as a service?

Answer (score 0):

A normal Windows Service does not have a keyboard nor mouse. There is no way of generating keyboard events for a non existing keyboard. You could try to configure your service as interactive like [here](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wci/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.cast_iron.live.doc/Secure_Connector/enablinginteractivemodeforwindowsservices.htm), or find another way to open your access database, like [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161016).