# Make PowerShell to hold key not press

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask for help.
I have little script that is pressing one key. But i would like to ask you how to make it to hold that key for 5 second mby? Script is

```
clear host
Do {
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
   [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait ("{G}")

Start-Sleep -seconds 60

} While ($true)
```

Thank you for help
Didnt try anything because i am begginer with powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In powershell how can a simulate the shift key being held down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447407/in-powershell-how-can-a-simulate-the-shift-key-being-held-down)